# How do they tell apart different parts on a stream of bits

Tags: network-protocols, binary-data

When data is transferred through a network it is obviously in binary form.

So it could be a number

```
1011001
```

and then some other data, maybe

```
1110100111001
```

That are sent together.

How can we tell them apart when they arrive. Is there some special flag that indicates the end of each data?

If yes how do we make sure that it is unique and we don't get confused?

Comment: Read about OSI layers or buy the book "computer networks" from Andy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a special bitstring pattern as the beginning or end of a stream and some protocols do this, but you would have to make it either long enough (256-bit for example) that it is highly unlikely that it appears in the normal data stream.

A more reliable way would be to escape the ending pattern if it appears in the normal data. You probably know how that works, because everybody came into contact of using `\` in strings at some point in time. They have to be escaped as `\\`.

A third way is applicable if you know in advance how long your stream will be, so you can send a length before actually sending the data.

The actual details are defined as the *protocol* and both sides must follow the structure of the protocol however it was defined.

Comment: There are much shorter ways to define a special signal.   I once worked with a protocol that defined, *"There shall never been 3 consecutive zeros in normal data.  Anytime 2 zeros are sent, they shall be followed by a 1, which is to be ignored.  If 3 zeros are found by the receiver, that is a special End-of-Data signal"*

Comment: @abelenky You're probably talking about zero bytes. Sure, that works, but that depends highly on the data one wants to send. For example, some file formats which are not well compressed have many consecutive 0x00 bytes in them.

Comment: I remember from a lecture long ago that there is also a technique where we create an ending flag that is created on the fly depending on the data before it. But I cant remember any details now.

Comment: @green_leaf Interesting idea, but how is it communicated to the receiver that this is the pattern? Maybe you can dig up the reference in your notes.

Comment: Yeah im trying to dig it out, must be somewhere in my data encryption notes. I think it was some sort of a line compression algorithm. I will definitely post it if I find it.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the Ethernet frame start with 8 byte preamble and start of frame delimiter, each byte is `10101010` (I am not sure about it)
Each data is generaly read by bytes (8 bits), Frame has defined structure:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame
Each frame contains a Packet:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_packet
Try googling something about this, but my answer is that there is defined structure, how to send data